# Havng problems responding to cmmitEditinStyle in tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am basically getting no response after i had gone into edit mode using :

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

I set commitEdittingstyle:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

To see that I would get a response, but i am not getting any sort of response after i had touch on the delete button.

any help?

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you saying that your commitEditingStyle delegate method is never called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This

[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

```
     // Delete  your data 

     // Update your table view
```

}

}